# Running Vue.js App on a different port with docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, deployment

I created a simple VueJS app with a very basic configuration. I used the webpack configuration to do this.

```
vue init webpack app
```

I build this simple `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3838
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

This app should run of a plattform which only listens to port 3838. Changing the Dockerfile to `EXPOSE 3838` did not work unfortunately.

```
sudo docker run -it -p 3838:3838 vuetest

Starting up http-server, serving dist
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

The container runs, but stil on 8080.

I´m quite unfamiliar with both VueJS and deploying, so can anyone help me? I guess the configuration to listen to 8080 might be set in a different file and the Dockerfile ignores it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application server runs by default on 8080

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Use flag -p 3838 to serve on that port. 
Docker is doing its job correctly, adjust in your CMD

`CMD [ "http-server", "-p 3838", "dist" ]`

Answer (score 2):

You can try just use the port 8080 of the continer and map it to port 3838 of your host.

```
#Dockerfile: delete the line -> Expose 3838
#Command line : $ sudo docker run -it -p 3838:8080 vuetest
```

This is an option not to add more lines to the Dockerfile.
Bye

Comment: OP says platform only has port 3838 port open to put a service behind.
At least that what i interpret from 'This app should run of a plattform which only listens to port 3838' ... could be wrong tho.

Comment: Hi. You're right to. If any answer solve his problem, it will be fine. I am sorry for my bad english. Greetings from Argentina

Comment: its cool, its hard enough to actually do these things, let alone discuss them via forum, even harder in a second or third language!
Your answer also could solve a similar problem for others!